# Flutter How to show gallery images in grid view

Tags: gridview, flutter, gallery

I tried everything to show gallery images in grid view in a flutter. But I couldn't find any appropriate method.

Answer (score 1):

What your trying to achieve is pretty complex(folder location,reading the files stored there, identifying the once you would like to display...)

There are two options:

Use this plugin if your not making an app specifically to access photos stored in the users phone without having your own UI

https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

If your developing an app specifically for accessing photos stored in the user's phone (with own UI)

The below links might help you:

https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery

https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view

There is even a widget for displaying mutliple widgets in the form of a grid called as GridView.

I would recommend breaking your problem into parts and then ask each of them individually in the form of multiple questions because your basically in a way asking an entire model for an app which would require a lot of explanation.

Comment: The problem with image_gallery is, that it is exceeding memory, because it's loading ALL Images at once! No broadcasting or streaming of MethodChannel! I definetly don't recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of widgets and add it in your gridview like this :

```
List<Widget> images = new List<Widget>();
images.add(Image.asset('assets/image.png', height: 35));
images.add(Image.asset('assets/image.png', height: 35));
images.add(Image.asset('assets/image.png', height: 35));

CustomScrollView(
    primary: false,
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverPadding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
        sliver: SliverGrid.count(
          mainAxisSpacing: 1, //horizontal space
          crossAxisSpacing: 1, //vertical space
          crossAxisCount: 3, //number of images for a row
          children: images
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: I have to add images from the gallery. Images are not in my assets.

Comment: Oops, sorry my bad. Did you try to make the list with this plugin ? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_multiple_image_picker

Answer (score 0):

Example on this link
https://github.com/follow2vivek/FlutterGallery

https://github.com/follow2vivek/FlutterGallery/blob/master/lib/tabview/image.dart

```
 @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) 
  {

    return FutureBuilder(
  future: StoragePath.imagesPath,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      List<dynamic> list = json.decode(snapshot.data);

      return Container(
        child: GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
          ),
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            ImageModel imageModel = ImageModel.fromJson(list[index]);
            return Container(
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FadeInImage(
                    image: FileImage(
                      File(imageModel.files[0]),
                    ),
                    placeholder: MemoryImage(kTransparentImage),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: double.infinity,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                    height: 30,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        imageModel.folderName,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontFamily: 'Regular'
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  },
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

step 1: import package on yaml file "gallery_view: ^0.0.4"
step 2: pub get (install package)
step 4: add images as url or from asset images
step 3: finally run the code b

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gallery_view/gallery_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(GalleryGridScreen());
}

class GalleryGridScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<GalleryGridScreen> {
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Gallery'),
        ),
        body: GalleryView(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          imageUrlList: [
"imageurl1",
"imageurl2",
"imageurl3",
"imageurl4",


        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use **[Photo Manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager)** package